# Why not include the sender into the EventArgs?

Tags: c#, events, conventions

The accepted convention for event subscribers is

```
void OnSomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs args);
```

But why was the EventArgs designed to leave out the sender? If so, the method signature could have been simplified to

```
void OnSomethingHappened(EventArgs args);
```

and one could check the sender by

```
args.Sender
```

Are there any arguments against this?

Comment: well... there's an *allocation* issue ... with the current pattern, *basic* events can use `EventArgs.Empty` - zero allocs; putting the sender into the args would force an alloc whenever invoked. Not sure that's actually part of the reason it was chosen like that, though

Comment: Agreed, keeping it as cheap as possible was key.  Back when this was [first invented](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26651&seqNum=3), long before .NET when machines still sucked mud.  Also the probable reason why C# does not have a *raise* accessor.